# DNN 8.0 (DotNetNuke) With async controller, await behavior is not as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, async-await, dotnetnuke

I am experimenting with an asynchronous call to an Azure Rest Api from a DNN module (this is for a client that uses the DNN platform and an older version of it namely 8.0). I need this call to retrieve the data before returning the View.

I made the controller async in order to be "await" getting the data from the azure rest api.

The behavior is unexpected. The code stops at this breakpoint(as in browser window with the blank view pops up but code after this point does not get executed) and the view is blank and never continues to the code populating the viewmodel for the page:

```
var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

Sometimes result (the db user) is returned properly from the db, but the view is still blank even though the other breakpoints after await have been hit in the controller... The view seems to be returned before the await call is completed? The View window gets focus before await is completed but as a blank page.

Any suggestions about what is going on please?

In the DNN Controller class:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() : DnnController
{
   ViewModel pageVM = new ViewModel();

   AuthenticationApi authService = new AuthenticationApi();
   var outcome = await authService.GetDbUser();  // AWAIT
   
   // populate the pageVM
   .................
   
   return View(pageVM);
   
}
```

In the Services folder, in the AuthenticationApi class:

```
public class AuthenticationApi
{
        public async Task<DbUser> GetDbUser()
        {
            string url = "https://mywebservicename.azurewebsites.net/api/applicants/46";

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            try
            {
                var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbUser>(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                return null;
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Does `httpClient.GetStringAsync` throw an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main response pipeline within DNN Platform is web-forms based and does not currently (even with version 9.6.2) support the usage of async/await in the main pipeline.

There is roadmap plans for this to be supported in version 10.x, however, additional changes are necessary to ensure that language features are not broken.

Some users have had success by adding this

```
aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext
```

Application setting with a value of true, however, it is known to break certain features of DNN Platform such as Localization.